# Showing that $\ln(\sec 3t+\tan 3t)=2\tanh^{-1}(\tan(3t/2))$

Tags: trigonometry

> I've been trying to show that
>   $$\ln(\sec 3t+\tan 3t)=2\tanh^{-1}(\tan(3t/2))$$

I used the identity
$$\tanh^{-1}x=\frac12\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$
to write:
$$\begin{array}{tcl}
2\tanh^{-1}(\tan(3t/2))&=&2\cdot\frac12\ln\dfrac{1+\tan(3t/2)}{1-\tan(3t/2)}\\
2\tanh^{-1}(\tan(3t/2))&=&\ln\dfrac{1+\tan(3t/2)}{1-\tan(3t/2)}\\
\end{array}$$
Then I used
$$\tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{1-\cos \theta}{\sin\theta}$$
to write:
$$\begin{array}{tcl}
2\tanh^{-1}(\tan(3t/2))&=&\ln\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1-\cos3t}{\sin3t}}{1-\dfrac{1-\cos 3t}{\sin 3t}}\\
2\tanh^{-1}(\tan(3t/2))&=&\ln\dfrac{\sin 3t+1-\cos 3t}{\sin 3t-1+\cos 3t}
\end{array}$$

Now, in order to show that
$$\ln(\sec 3t+\tan 3t)=\ln\dfrac{\sin 3t+1-\cos 3t}{\sin 3t-1+\cos 3t}$$
I need to show that
$$\sec 3t+\tan 3t=\dfrac{\sin 3t+1-\cos 3t}{\sin 3t-1+\cos 3t}$$
Now,
$$\begin{array}{tcl}
\sec3t+\tan3t&=&\dfrac{1}{\cos 3t}+\dfrac{\sin 3t}{\cos 3t}\\
\sec3t+\tan3t&=&\dfrac{1+\sin 3t}{\cos 3t}
\end{array}$$

Now, I am stuck. How do I show that:
$$\frac{\sin 3t+1-\cos 3t}{\sin 3t-1+\cos 3t}=\frac{1+\sin 3t}{\cos 3t}$$
Here is some Matlab code that seemingly verifies the identity.

```
t=linspace(-1.5,1/2,1000);
y1=(sin(3*t)+1-cos(3*t))./(sin(3*t)-1+cos(3*t));
y2=(1+sin(3*t))./cos(3*t);
plot(t,y1,'b','LineWidth',4),hold on
plot(t,y2,'r','LineWidth',2)
hold off
```

And the image.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. To prove 
$$\frac{\sin 3t+1-\cos 3t}{\sin 3t-1+\cos 3t}=\frac{1+\sin 3t}{\cos 3t},$$
you need 
$$(\sin 3t+1-\cos 3t)\cos 3t=(\sin 3t-1+\cos 3t)(1+\sin 3t).$$
Expand it:
$$\sin 3t\cos 3t+\cos 3t-\cos^2 3t=\sin 3t-1+\cos 3t+\sin^2 3t-\sin 3t+\cos 3t\sin 3t,$$
which can be simplified to 
$$\cos^23t+\sin^2 3t=1.$$

Comment: I'd like to thank your for your assistance

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove the identity $$\ln(\sec 3t+\tan 3t)=2\tanh^{-1}(\tan(3t/2))$$

We differentiate both sides and show that the derivatives are the same.

Note that $$ \frac {d}{dt}  \ln(\sec 3t+\tan 3t) = 3 \sec 3t$$

Also we have  $$ \frac {d}{dt} 2\tanh^{-1}(\tan (3t/2))$$

$$=\frac {2\sec ^ 2 ( 3t/2)}{1-\tan ^2 (3t/2)} (3/2)=3 \sec 3t$$

Thus the differennce of the two functions is a constant.

Upon evaluating the functions at $t=0$ we obtain the identity.

Comment: I'd like to thank your for your assistance

Comment: Thank for your attention and understanding.